# Using sed to substitute mathematical expressions

Tags: regex, sed

I am struggling to use sed to replace the mathematical expressions. For even though the regular expression `\( \- xi\*\*2 \+ 2\*xi \- 1\)` [matches](https://regex101.com/r/raTldY/1) the string "( - xi**2 + 2*xi - 1)" [sed does not perform](https://rextester.com/KUC7567) the substitution:

```
echo "( - xi**2 + 2*xi - 1)" | sed -e 's/\( \- xi\*\*2 \+ 2\*xi \- 1\)/k1/g'
```

Please advise.

Comment: You are using the online regex tester wrong, you have a PCRE option set and `sed` only supports POSIX regex flavor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You selected the PCRE2 option at regex101.com, while `sed` only supports POSIX regex flavor.

Here, you are using a POSIX BRE flavor, so the expression will look like

```sh
#!/bin/bash
s="( - xi**2 + 2*xi - 1)"
sed 's/( - xi\*\*2 + 2\*xi - 1)/k1/g' <<< "$s"
```

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/oYqc6W). In POSIX BRE, this expression means:

- `(` - a `(` char (when not escaped, matches a `(` char)
- `- xi` - a fixed string
- `\*\*` - a `**` string (`*` is a quantifier in POSIX BRE that means *zero or more*)
- `2 + 2` - a fixed `2 + 2` string as `+` is a mere `+` char in POSIX BRE
- `\*` - a `*` char
- `xi - 1)` - a literal  `xi - 1)` fixed string, `)` in POSIX BRE matches a literal `)` char.

If you plan to use POSIX ERE, you will need to escape `(`, `)` and `+` in your regex:

```sh
sed -E 's/\( - xi\*\*2 \+ 2\*xi - 1\)/k1/g'
```

Note the difference between `-e` (that says that the next thing is the script to the commands to be executed) and `-E` (that means the regex flavor is POSIX ERE).

Answer (score 0):

With your shown samples, please try following in `sed`. Since you are doing a pattern matching, then IMHO rather than doing substitution we can match pattern and then simply print the new value(by keeping printing off for all lines until we ask `sed` to print).

```
s="( - xi**2 + 2*xi - 1)"
sed -n 's/( - xi\*\*2 + 2\*xi - 1)/k1/p' <<< "$s"
```

***Explanation:*** Stopping printing of lines by `-n` option in `sed` then in main program using regex `( - xi\*\*2 + 2\*xi - 1)` to match as per requirement and if match is found printing `k1` in output.

Answer (score 0):

Using `sed`

```
$ sed 's/( - \(xi\)\(\*\)\22 + 2\2\1 - 1)/k1/' <(echo "( - xi**2 + 2*xi - 1)")
```